# Change fade color or whatever of NumberPicker and DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, picker, numberpicker

When i press increment or decrement button of NumberPicker or DatePicker will appear fade color in button. I wanna disable or change this color and disable click increment or decrement button. My problem encountered on android 4.1.2. I have searched solution to fix this problem about 2 days but I have not found. I hope to receive your help. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhDBn.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7xQj.png